# Page Redirect using javascript in Sharepoint o365

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using SharePoint O365.
I created a custom js file with javascript + Html .The js file is loaded through content Editor webpart. The page say (Page1) which loads the js file has filters which loads same page with parameters and displays results. The results has hyperlinks which onclick redirects user to Editform page with ID and Source as parameters.The source url has the current url with parameters.
If user clicks on save or cancel from EditForm page it should land back to Page 1 which it does but the filter parameters value which was part of source url is removed .
Any reason why?

Comment: only the "=<value>" gets removed .the source url with parameter remains intact.

Comment: the same code works in SP 2010 but  not in SP online